# Python Regex Syntax Troubles: Match Within Six Words

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find a match within six words of a key word. With this I am trying

```
regex_search = re.compile("(?=keyword)(\s+\S+|$){0,6}<match_string>")
```

But this doesn't seem to work for me as seen in example below.

```
>>> search_string = "The dog happily ran after his ball" 
>>> regex_search = re.compile('(?<=ran)(\s+\S+|$){0,2}dog')
>>> print(re.search(regex_search, search_string))
None
```

I would expect this to return a search object.

Comment: Whats your expected output?

Comment: I think "dog" is creating the non-match, try doing `|dog`...

Comment: The `dog` appears to the right of `ran`, thus you won't have a match even with `ran\s+(?:\S+\s+){0,6}dog`, but `ran\s+(?:\S+\s+){0,6}ball` will. Also, see [`ran\s+(?:\S+\s+){0,6}dog|dog\s+(?:\S+\s+){0,6}ran`](https://regex101.com/r/rdiLjX/1).

Comment: Thank you very much Wiktor! This fixed the probelm

Answer (score 0):

The `dog` appears to the right of `ran`, thus you won't have a match here. You may use an alternation group to match what is between `ran` and `dog` or `dog` and `ran`:

```
ran\s+(?:\S+\s+){0,6}dog|dog\s+(?:\S+\s+){0,6}ran
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rdiLjX/1).

**Details**

- `ran` - `ran`
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespace chars
- `(?:\S+\s+){0,6}` - 0 to 6 occurrences of:

  - `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars
  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespace chars
- `dog` - a `dog`
- `|` - or
- `dog\s+(?:\S+\s+){0,6}ran` - similar to the above, just `dog` is switched with `ran`.

NOTE that to match `dog` and `ran` as whole words you can use `\b`:

```
rx = r'\bran\s+(?:\S+\s+){0,6}dog\b|\bdog\s+(?:\S+\s+){0,6}ran\b'
```

When declaring regex patterns, it is best practice to rely on raw string literals, note the `r` prefix (so, no need to escape `\` in `\b`).